# React app works on Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, webpack

My project runs fine in Chrome (without errors). When I open it in Firefox, however, it shows the following errors:

```
TypeError: RealRTCPeerConnection is undefined app:190:1
TypeError: b is undefined compose.js:29
```

I'm not using `RealRTCPeerConnection` in my code, so I'm assuming this error is from a dependency. The problem is I'm not sure what dependency that'd be, or how to go about troubleshooting it. I've tried looking online and troubleshooting it myself, but I didn't find anything useful.

Also note that I'm running the `Desktop` bundle. Here's my project's config:

#### `webpack.config.js`

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    desktop: [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/js/Desktop/index'
    ],
    mobile: './src/js/Mobile/index'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./src/bundles/'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/src/bundles/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(), // Don't hot reload if there is an error
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve('./node_modules/')
        ],
        include: [
          path.resolve('./src/js/')
        ],
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
          'eslint-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname + '/node_modules'),
      path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/js')
    ],
    alias: {
      Common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/Common'),
      Desktop: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/Desktop'),
      Mobile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/Mobile'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

#### `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "watch": "node server.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint": "^4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-preact": "^1.1.6",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jsdom": "11.3.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "nock": "^9.0.22",
    "radium": "^0.19.4",
    "react-a11y": "^0.3.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^3.5.4",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "airbnb-prop-types": "^2.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "color": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "preact": "^8.2.6",
    "preact-compat": "^3.17.0",
    "preact-material-components": "^1.3.1",
    "preact-redux": "^2.0.3",
    "preact-router": "^2.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.4.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "redux-undo": "^0.6.1",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src/js"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./src/js/Common/shim.js",
      "./src/js/Common/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
}
```

#### `server.js`

```js
var webpack = require('webpack')
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
  historyApiFallback: true,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  overlay: {
    errors: true,
    warnings: true,
  },
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err)

  console.log('Listening at 0.0.0.0:3000')
})
```

#### `babel.rc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
      ],
      "presets": [
        ["env", { "modules": false }],
        "react",
        "stage-1"
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
      ],
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react",
        "stage-1"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to Adblock ? https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6030. Hope this helps!

Comment: @PhilippeSultan I tried disabling it and loading the page, but unfortunately the error is still there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

As shown in my `package.json`, I'm using `redux-devtools`. I had Redux DevTools installed on Chrome, but not Firefox. The site works fine after installing it on Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

A browser without the Redux DevTools Extension may produce an error if the Redux store is not properly created. It may happen that the error still produces even though the extension is not working in the browser for some kind of error installation. So if the extension is not working make sure too uninstall it.

To **fix the error on browsers without the extension**, create the Redux store with `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` instead of `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
));
```

See documentation:
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup

To fix the error on browsers without the extension and to **improve performance in production**, the recommended best practice is to use the `redux-devtools-extension` npm package:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/logOnlyInProduction';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  // options like actionSanitizer, stateSanitizer
});

const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

And if you want to **disable the extension on production**, use the `developmentOnly` helper instead of `logOnlyInProduction`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  // options like actionSanitizer, stateSanitizer
});

const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

Here you have a **working complete code example** of `store.js` where the Redux store is created:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

To **install** the `redux-devtools-extension` npm package you can use:

```
npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension
```

But for **production builds** you may need instead:

```
npm install redux-devtools-extension
```

Check documentation: 
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm

Aditional info:
https://medium.com/@zalmoxis/using-redux-devtools-in-production-4c5b56c5600f
https://medium.com/@zalmoxis/improve-your-development-workflow-with-redux-devtools-extension-f0379227ff83

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with Redux DevTools. This is what worked for me:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk,
    ),
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
      : compose,
  ),
);
```

Note that `compose` does not handle `undefined` so you have to use a ternary & return `compose`.

In other words `(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') && (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())` does not work

Other possible solutions can be found on the redux GitHub page: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2033

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I checked for the "clientInformation" property on the window object somewhere in my code and that doesn't exist in Firefox but it does in Chrome.

A simple optional chain (window.clientInformation?.userAgent.....) fixed it up quickly.